# Spring Cloud Config server authentication

Tags: spring-security, environment-variables, spring-cloud, keytool, spring-cloud-config

Is it better to store the config server username and password as an environment variable (both in the client and server), or by using a keystore? The keystore password is anyway stored as an environment variable, so why actually use a keystore? Or is there a better way to implement authentication in the Spring Cloud Config server?

Comment: What kind of authentication to use is primarily opinion - based .No matter what approach you will take , unless you have another explicit way of masking your secret ( key, password) it will be in plain text.

Comment: @IndraneelBende So no problem even if I store the username and password as environment variables on both client and the config server?

Comment: I wouldn't say that is exactly 'secure' . Depends if this is a enterprise deployment. I would be surprised if they allow you to go to production with plaintext password.

Comment: @IndraneelBende The best way you say is to use the keytool...and specify the encrypted password in the properties files?

Comment: Like i said its subjective. Different people would have different views.

Comment: @IndraneelBende Okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, config server is ONLY for backend services, but not for clients. We have multiple clients, like iOS, Android and Web app. Each kind of client will manage their own configurations.

Furthermore, we simply use HTTP basic authentication on config server, and store the username and password as instance variables.  So the username and password will be not be exposed in source code level. On the other hand, our config server is not exposed to public network.

Hope this will give you some hints.